# How to show name of first item followed by the number of total items present in the row of expandable table in react js?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-fullstack, react-table-v7

As shown in the picture, I have created a similar collapsible table, but I am unable to display the number of items in the collapsible rows. I **am referring to the headings written in blue colour** (in the picture)

Can someone help me to understand, how I can display the name of first items followed by the number of remaining items in heading of each main row ( for eg ( basketball..+2). Also I am using api call to fetch data in the table

[image: table preview]

```
  enter code here
    export const columns = [
  {
    Header: () => (
      <div />
    ),
    accessor: 'name',
    maxWidth: 300,
    Cell: row => (
      <div className='first-column'>{row.value}</div>
    )
  }
];

export const subComponent = row => {
  return (
    <div>
      {row.original.types.map((type, id) => {
        return (
          <div className='subRow' key={ id }>{ type.name }</div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export const data = [
  {
    id: '12345',
    name: 'sports',
    types: [
      {
        name: 'basketball',
        id: '1'
      },
      {
        name: 'soccer',
        id: '2'

      },
      {
        name: 'baseball',
        id: '3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '678910',
    name: 'food',
    types: [
      {
        name: 'pizza',
        id: '4'
      },
      {
        name: 'hamburger',
        id: '5'

      },
      {
        name: 'salad',
        id: '6'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: so where is your code? can you add a codesandbox?

Comment: @Apostolos added sample code in question

Comment: cannot help you with this sample. i would suggest you created a codesandbox with a full example with dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

First, your columns have to use `useMemo` hooks. You can read the details [here](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#table-options).

```js
const columns = useMemo(() => [
    ...
],[])
```

Next, change the **types** property into **subRows** in your data so the `subRows` rows can be auto rendered and no additional subRow component required.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "12345",
    name: "sports",
    subRows: [      // <---- change types into subRows
      {
        name: "basketball",
        id: "1",
      },
      ...
    ],
  },
  ...
];
```

The **subRows** informations is also required to get the remaining items in heading. Here, we grab and describe the information at column's **Cell**

```js
     {
        Header: () => <div />,
        accessor: "name",
        maxWidth: 300,
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          // we can get subRows info here after change types into subRows
          const { subRows } = row,
            // describe the required information here
            isSubRow = subRows[0] ? false : true,
            firstSubRowName = subRows[0] ? subRows[0].original.name : "",
            remainingSubRowsLength = subRows[1] ? `..+${subRows.length - 1}` : "";
          return (
            <span>
              {row.original.name}
              // conditionally render the additional info
              {!isSubRow && (
                <span
                  style={{ color: "blue" }}
                >{` (${firstSubRowName}${remainingSubRowsLength})`}</span>
              )}
            </span>
          );
        }
     }
```

And the final code will become:

```js
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useTable, useExpanded } from "react-table";

const data = [
  {
    id: "12345",
    name: "sports",
    subRows: [
      {
        name: "basketball",
        id: "1"
      },
      {
        name: "soccer",
        id: "2"
      },
      {
        name: "baseball",
        id: "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "678910",
    name: "food",
    subRows: [
      {
        name: "pizza",
        id: "4"
      },
      {
        name: "hamburger",
        id: "5"
      },
      {
        name: "salad",
        id: "6"
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: () => null,
        id: "expander",
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          return (
            <span {...row.getToggleRowExpandedProps()}>
              {row.depth === 0 && (row.isExpanded ? "▼" : "►")}
            </span>
          );
        }
      },
      {
        Header: () => <div />,
        accessor: "name",
        maxWidth: 300,
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          const { subRows } = row,
            isSubRow = subRows[0] ? false : true,
            firstSubRowName = subRows[0] ? subRows[0].original.name : "",
            remainingSubRowsLength = subRows[1] ? `..+${subRows.length - 1}` : "";
          return (
            <span>
              {row.original.name}
              {!isSubRow && (
                <span
                  style={{ color: "blue" }}
                >{` (${firstSubRowName}${remainingSubRowsLength})`}</span>
              )}
            </span>
          );
        }
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, rows, prepareRow } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data
    },
    useExpanded
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h1>React Table v.7 SubRows</h1>
      <br />
      <table
        {...getTableProps()}
        style={{ borderCollapse: "collapse", width: "50%" }}
      >
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps}>
          {rows.map((row, index) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr
                {...row.getRowProps}
                key={index}
                style={{
                  border: "1px solid black",
                  height: "30px",
                  background: row.subRows[0] ? "#e9ebfb" : "#fff"
                }}
              >
                {row.cells.map((cell, i) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()} key={i}>
                      {cell.render("Cell")}
                    </td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the example at codesanbox:

[image: Edit romantic-feynman-lgm0cz]

Comment: Yohanes really thanks for the help. This is what I was looking for. The subrow part makes absolute sense.